# La imagen del renderizado del mayor elemento con contenido se ha cargado en diferido

Tags: wordpress

Amigos tengo este problema, deseo mejorar esta métrica, pero me sale esta advertencia ¿que aconsejan para mejorar esta metrica?

[image: la intencion es dejarlo en verde]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Eso ocurre porque la imagen tiene el atributo **loading="lazy"** y es la primera imagen visible que se carga, es decir, es el LCP (Largest Contenful Paint).

El LCP mide cuánto tarda en renderizarse el elemento más grande, en este caso, es esa imagen, y el atributo loading="lazy" lo que hace es que retrasa la carga de imágenes hasta que están próximas al viewport, lo cuál es útil para todas la imágenes que no están **above the fold**. Básicamente, ese atributo hace que se retrase la carga de ese elemento, y eso termina afectando al LCP.

Esto podrías resolverlo eliminando ese atributo de la imagen, pero parece que estas utilizando un plugin de optimización de imágenes o de caché. Revisa si tienen alguna opción para evitar aplicar lazyload a ciertas imágenes y añades la url de esa imágen.